# how to identify the port on which Rsyslog running?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to setup the flume agent to collect the log events from Rsyslog, but I dont have root permission/sudoer to figure out which port syslog is running on/ and where it is running on TCP or UDP so I can configure flume agent accordingly.
Is there any way to know exactly what is the port that Rsyslog deamon running on?

Below are command that I have used to identify Rsyslog Deamon process

```
ldnpsr000001131$ ps -ef | grep syslog
root      4874     1  0 Feb04 ?        00:00:14 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try  `netstat -natupel |grep syslog` and you'll get all connections : active and listening